# How to say close the door but not completely?

Tags: word-choice

What verb should I use if I want to tell someone to close the door but not completely?

For example, lets say I don't have a key and want to go to the backyard. I wanna tell my friend:

> If you want to come outside please xxxx(close) the door.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know a single word for this. I would say

> Leave the door ajar.

Comment: Agreed. See the definition of ajar: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ajar?s=t

Comment: Or, "Please leave the door partially open." If you are concerned that the person may not be paying careful attention, you might add more words for emphasis, like, "Please close the door but not all the way because we don't want to get locked out" or whatever.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't suggest what is to me a more natural expression "Push the door to".  (See definition 24 [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/to?s=t))